# chrome extension login issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is a website and I created a chrome extension for this website, if user have log in the website, is there any solution to let user don't need to log in the chrome extension again? 
Anyone can help me？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: in your background page, add an iframe with a src="yoursitesurl". Then embed that iframe into body of the background page. The document may not have a "body", so you may need to create that also. Then you can add the iframe to the body. the iframe will not load until you add it to the body, from my experience.

Second: add the following to your manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["yoursiteurl.com"],
        "js":["content.js"],    
        "all_frames":true
    }
]
```

Then create the "content.js" file. It will be loaded into you website in the iframe. In the content.js you will write JavaScript that will harvest the data from your site that you need. Then you will pass it back to the background page.

Third: pass it back to the background page. To pass the data from your content_script to the background page, do the following:

```
//In the content.js
chrome.extension.sendMessage(undefined,{data:<thedateyougather>});

//In your background page
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender){
    //in here you write the code that will display the data from your site.
});
```

In the onMessage listener in the background page, you can do anything you want with the data from your site. You can save it to localStorage. You could alert it to the user. You could pass it to the popup.html. I am not sure what you want to do once you have the data, so this is where I stop, as I am not sure what you want to do next.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, it works, but i don't know why we need a iframe in background page. In my understanding, a content script is enough. Content script pass a message to background page when user login my website.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your site is like and I don't fully understand your requirements. If your site is 100 % server side generated content then ajax in a content script MIGHT work. If your site loads things with ajax onload then u have to use the iframe. Since I don't know your knowledge level AND I don't know your requirements I gave you an answer that would work no matter the details of the situation.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much for your help.I think I should do some adjustments.